# More efficient for a server to have a persistent mySQL connection, or to connect when needed

Tags: mysql, optimization

I'm working on a chat server which uses a MySQL database for user login and authentication (messages are kept in memory and only saved to or loaded from the database on shutdown and startup, respectively). Each chatroom is implemented as a separate process so that, if one chatroom goes down, the entire server is not dead. When the user connects, and each time he posts a message, the room server process reads his authentication info from the database. Re-authenticating on each message is required to prevent multiple sessions by the same user. Presuming that messages are posted at a reasonable rate (1 message per user every ~5-10 seconds), is it more efficient for the room server to maintain a persistent MySQL connection over the entire lifetime of the server, or for the server to connect, make its request, and disconnect? Does the answer change if it is possible that the room is idle (no messages) for a few days at a time? And lastly, does the answer change if the MySQL server is running on the same hardware vs. on a different machine on the network?

Comment: Take a look at [connection pooling](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/connection_pooling_with_connectorj.html)...

Answer (score 0):

Establishing a connection can be an expensive thing - from a network perspective as well as the authentication against the database.  I've moved sites from single connections being opened/closed to connection pools and seen a huge performance boost (>= 20%, if I recall).

Definitely the way to go.